# Meshlab not preserving texture mapping when editing faces and exporting to DAE

Tags: texture-mapping, collada, meshlab

I am using Meshlab to open an .OBJ file, delete out some of the faces and vertices, and then save as a .DAE (Collada) format. The program makes it very easy to do.

However, the original OBJ model has 3 separate texture surfaces on the model, each with a different texture assigned. When I finish editing the model and export the DAE file, it seems to merge all the surfaces together into one surface for the whole model. This makes it impossible to assign the proper texture to the portions of the model that previously had separate textures and they look broken.

Just for reference, if I use Blender to import the same OBJ file and export to DAE, the original texture mappings of the OBJ file are preserved in the exported DAE.

Is there a trick in exporting to DAE without losing the original texture surface mappings, for cases where there are multiple textures in the model? Am I missing a step or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug! You should report the error in the [Issues](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/issues) tab in the official github repository!
List the operations you do to replicate the problem, and if it is possible share the 3D object input file. This will help the team to replicate and then solve the issue!